# Links are't opening via terminal

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome

When I click a link from terminal then nothing happens. But when I do `right click > open a link` it opens google chrome in a new windows with a new tab.

And also I noticed something weird that, in dash when I hover pointer over Google chrome icon it shows **https://www.facebook.com - Google chrome**

I am running Ubuntu 16.04

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Web Links in the Terminal**

Clicking on the terminal is an option to select that window.  That is all it does.  If you have other windows open and click on a different window, that window will be selected.

The terminal also has right click features.  The terminal itself will recognize a web link and display it appropriately so that the user can recognize it as a link.  The right click off the terminal has a number of features which includes copy or open a hovered link.  The open option will open the ink in your default browser.

**Chrome's Launcher title**

The launcher will sometimes attach the name of the Chrome title that is opened to the launcher when you lock it to the Launcher.  This is a characteristic of Chrome that I don't see happening with other applications.  This is a glitch that happens sometimes.  It doesn't affect the actual launching of the browser, just the title giving to the icon.

It used to happen to me frequently in Ubuntu 14.04.  I don't experience it with 16.04.  It might be back affecting 16.10 until the developers fix it again.

I believe the glitch is with Chrome, because I had a launcher problem with Chrome and Cairo-dock.  The developer of Cairo-dock worked with me to fix the menu issue.  He described it as a Chrome glich.